# Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values error on soapUI

Tags: json, postman, soapui, get-request

I have a json get request which returns the current version of the application. When I send the request from Postman it returns the value as 1.14.5 but when I send the get request from SoapUI it throws this error : Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): Expected space separating root-level values

Any suggestions on this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Since my response is not a json one, i got this error. In raw response and html response tabs, I can see my response line.